# Unable to get user info with reviews

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using Graph API Route to get reviews of a page using `{page}/rating`. But there is no reviewer information in the response like name and image.

```
{pageId}/ratings?fields=open_graph_story,reviewer,has_review,has_rating,rating
```

I'm following this documentation:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings
```

How can I get the reviewer information with reviews?

Comment: i believe this is for privacy reasons, what do you need the private details for?

Comment: I want the name and image of the user with the review, I have seen a website where they have this information.

Comment: can you share the website?

Comment: nicejob.com - create your account here > product settings > Review Sites > connect facebook